# When i use startActivityForResult ,I am not getting the result back?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I tried the code below in the first activity

```
Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClaimintimationFilesList.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 1);
```

This is the code i used in second activity

```
package com.assuretech.ku.claimintimation;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.assuretech.ku.R;


public class ClaimintimationFilesList extends ListActivity {

private String path;


 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.files_list_browse);

    path = "/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
      path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }

    setTitle(path);



    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    List values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
      setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
      for (String file : list) {
        if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
          values.add(file);
        }
      }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);

    // Put the data into the list
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

 @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
      filename = path + filename;
    } else {
      filename = path + File.separator + filename;
    }
    if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClaimintimationFilesList.class);
      intent.putExtra("path", filename);
      startActivity(intent);
    } else {



        Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("path",filename);
        System.out.println("Filename in list.."+filename);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();


        //Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, Reportclaim.class);
          intent.putExtra("path", filename);
          startActivity(intent);*/
        /*System.out.println("Filename.."+filename);
        Reportclaim obj=new Reportclaim();
          obj.policy_rep.setText(filename);*/
    }

    this.finish();

  }



}
```

But on activity result i am not geeting the filename

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
       // if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
             filename=data.getStringExtra("path");
             System.out.println("Filename.."+filename);
             policy_rep.setText(filename);
         }
        //}
       /* if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
            System.out.println("Noresult....");
        }*/
    }
```

When i tried the commented code i got Noresult printed in the logcat.

Comment: Did you add a `finish();` in yout second activity code?

Comment: Ya i added finish(); at the end

Comment: Please Post your complete method in which you are set the setResult

Comment: edited secondacitivty code

Comment: If Selected item is directory then why you are launch same activity ?Just refresh the adapter.

Comment: If you can select the directory after coming from the first activity,after that if you can select the file ,on acitvity result in the first activity is not called

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code and checked ..Its working for me.
Make sure filename variable is not null and empty before sending..

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 1);
        }
    });


}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
       // if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
            String filename=data.getStringExtra("path");
             System.out.println("Filename.."+filename);
           //  policy_rep.setText(filename);
         }
        //}
       /* if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
            System.out.println("Noresult....");
        }*/
    }


}
```

public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("path","arjun");
    System.out.println("Filename in list.."+"arjun");
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
private String path;
private List values;
private  ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.files_list_browse);

path = "/";
if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
  path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
}

setTitle(path);



// Read all files sorted into the values-array
values = new ArrayList();
setData(path);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1,    values);
setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
private void setData(String path){
    values.clear();
     File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.canRead()) {
          setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
        }
        String[] list = dir.list();
        if (list != null) {
          for (String file : list) {
            if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
              values.add(file);
            }
          }
        }
        Collections.sort(values);

        // Put the data into the list


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
  filename = path + filename;
} else {
  filename = path + File.separator + filename;
}
if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
 setData(filename);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {



    Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("path",filename);
    System.out.println("Filename in list.."+filename);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();


    //Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, Reportclaim.class);
      intent.putExtra("path", filename);
      startActivity(intent);*/
    /*System.out.println("Filename.."+filename);
    Reportclaim obj=new Reportclaim();
      obj.policy_rep.setText(filename);*/
}

this.finish();

}
```